# Extract embedded profile from ipa in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, ios, ota

I want to create a web server like testflight. I want to upload only the ipa file and fetch the provision profile. So the user don't need to add the provision profile. Is there a solution for this?

Also, how is testflight working to install an application in a device?

Comment: did my anwer help in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the embedded profile in your ad-hoc distribution will install on the user's device automatically while downloaded OTA. Check Apples docs on [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS 4 Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html), section *Installing Apps Wirelessly*. For a full sample read [deleted]

Edit:
The link above was broken, and seems to have moved to: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

Also since iOS 7.0.3, the plist (not the ipa) must be hosted on a ssl secured site (https).

Comment: The second link appears to be broken.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for the info. I updated the link and added some info for https usage.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants a "real" answer you would use PHP to extract the IPA(zip) and the provision is available in the XXXX.app folder in the Payload folder

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('FirstApp.ipa') === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('/dir/');
        $zip->close();
    }
```